# Gradle how to change version number in source code

Tags: gradle

Java code:

```
public static String VERSION = "version_number";
```

Gradle build.gradle

```
version = '1.0'
```

How to set the version in java code from grade? The version must be in source code.

Is there a convenient way?  A not-so-nice way:

1. copy the java file to another location, e.g. build/changed-source
2. change the version in the source, by replacing token
3. add the build/changed-source in main source set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to similar to your not-so-nice way, but slightly easier. Consider a file in `templates/BuildInfo.java`:

```
package __PACKAGE;

public class BuildInfo {
    private static final String version = "__VERSION";
    private static final String buildTimestamp = "__BUILD_TIMESTAMP";

    public String toString() {
        return "version         : " + version + "\n" + 
               "build timestamp : " + buildTimestamp + "\n";
    }
}
```

This file can then be "stamped" with information as first thing in the `compileJava` task and written to `src/main/java/your/package/BuildInfo.java`:

```
def targetPackage = 'net/codetojoy/util'
def targetPackageJava = 'net.codetojoy.util'

def appVersion = project.appVersion // from gradle.properties
def buildTimeStamp = new Date().toString()

compileJava { 
    doFirst {
        ant.mkdir(dir: "${projectDir}/src/main/java/${targetPackage}")
        def newBuildInfo = new File("${projectDir}/src/main/java/${targetPackage}/BuildInfo.java")
        def templateBuildInfo = new File("${projectDir}/templates/TemplateBuildInfo.java")

        newBuildInfo.withWriter { def writer ->
            templateBuildInfo.eachLine { def line ->
                def newLine = line.replace("__PACKAGE", targetPackageJava)
                                  .replace("__VERSION", appVersion)
                                  .replace("__BUILD_TIMESTAMP", buildTimeStamp)
                writer.write(newLine + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A working example is provided [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_51937034). Everything would be stored in source-control **except** the `src/main/java/your/package/BuildInfo.java` file. Note the version would be stored in `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 8):

I'd do similar to Michael Easter but with these differences

1. Store generated sources separately from main sources (`src/main/java` and `$buildDir/generated/java`). This has the added benefit of not needing custom gitignore
2. Generate in a subdirectory of `$buildDir` so that clean task will delete the generated sources
3. Use a separate task for code generation with proper up-to-date & skip support
4. Use [Copy.expand(Map)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:expand(java.util.Map)) to do the token replacement
5. Since its directory based, everything in `src/template/java` will have tokens replaced. You can easily add more templates in future

`src/template/java/com/foo/BuildInfo.java`

```
package com.foo;
public class BuildInfo {
    public static String getVersion() {
        return "${version}";
    }
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
task generateJava(type:Copy) {
    def templateContext = [version: project.version]
    inputs.properties templateContext // for gradle up-to-date check 
    from 'src/template/java' 
    into "$buildDir/generated/java" 
    expand templateContext 
} 
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir "$buildDir/generated/java" // add the extra source dir 
compileJava.dependsOn generateJava // wire the generateJava task into the DAG
```

Comment: Very nice and clean solution! you could also do `sourceSets {
    template {
        java {` to be able to use in an ide